# How do I approach creating a `thread` fixture with `py.test`?

Tags: python, multithreading, pytest, fixtures

I'm looking into making a magic fixture which launches some threads.

Basically, I want my code to be able to do this:

```py
def test_with_background_thread(threads):
    def background_thread():
        while True:
            print("running in background")

    threads.run_background(background_thread)

# running in background!
# running in background!
# running in background!
#: the test stops execution here, so the `background_thread` here just stops

#: ...no more output
```

I tried adding a KillableThread implementation, which yields a thread like so:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def thread():
    _thread = KillableThread()
    yield _thread
    if _thread.is_alive():
        _thread.kill()
```

Yes, I am aware that 'killing' threads is a bad practice, but I don't see how else I could stop the `while True` loop. No, I don't want to use a `threading.Event`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `asyncio`, and the `pytest-asyncio` library.
Example:

```
import asyncio
import pytest

async def background_thread():
    while True:
        print("running in background") # pytest won't print this despite --capture=no 
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

@pytest.fixture
async def background_task_fixture():
    task = asyncio.create_task(background_thread())
    yield task
    task.cancel()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_with_background_task():

    # do your test
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

The only drawback of this solution is that `pytest` will be capturing the printed messages, and there does not seem to be away to make them appear again, ever. Running the same code outside `pytest` will print messages to `stdout`.